# How to use global value in RecyclerAdapter on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In want use `RecyclerView` into my application and i want use some data into `adapter` of this `RecyclerView`.
I write codes, but **not found** my data into `ViewHolder` , i can't access this data into `ViewHolder`!

**My adapter codes:**

```
class CategoryAdapter(private val catsModel: MutableList<HomeCatsListResponse.Data.Result>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var userData = ADDRESS_LOCATION_LAT

    override
    fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.type_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val type = catsModel[position]
        holder.bindData(type)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return catsModel.size
    }

    fun setData(catsList: MutableList<HomeCatsListResponse.Data.Result>) {
        catsModel.addAll(catsList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val txtName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_item)

        fun bindData(type: HomeCatsListResponse.Data.Result) {
            txtName.text = type.name
        }
    }
}
```

I can't use **userData** into `ViewHolder` !!!

How can i use fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define userData as companion object in CategoryAdapter

```
companion object {
    lateinit var userData =""
}
```

Init it inside CategoryAdapter

```
   init {
        userData = ADDRESS_LOCATION_LAT
   }
```

And then access from ViewHolder

```
fun accessVar(){
   print(userData )
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, your answer is very help me and wonderful . thanks (sorry i can't upvote, because my reputation is low)

Comment: This works like a charm and I've upvoted this. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the `#onBindViewHolder` method.

For example you want to use `userData` in your `ViewHolder`. You can write a method in your ViewHolder that takes userData parameter.

Say you can make use of your bindData method like this.

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
     RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val txtName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_item)

    fun bindData(userDate: UserData, type: 
        HomeCatsListResponse.Data.Result) {

        //Use useData here

        txtName.text = type.name
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val type = catsModel[position]
    holder.bindData(userData, type)

}
```